# product image is not showing

Tags: product-images

my problem is that i have product image url in DB but not found/missing in the folder, and it is showing product image url by inspecting the image, default image is still in the folder but it can't display the default image where product image path is available in DB but missing the image in that path/folder...

plz let me know how to resolve missing product image issue as i tried through htaccess and also let me know tha exact url of product page..

Comment: Did you check images available in media folder or not

Comment: Hello Maz. Are you able to "manually" upload a file (e.g. with Filezilla) on the related media catalog product folder?

Comment: no buddy from stockinthechannel i import the feed into my site

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the read write permission of your media folder